# MySQL Select statement with several joins returns duplicated records

Tags: mysql, select, unique

I have 4 tables with the following structure:

```
Table Groups
  Groupid
  groupname
  groupadmin

Table GroupMembership
  devid
  groupid

Table GroupLocator
  devid
  name
  pass
  color
  sampling
  connected
  forget
  trace

Table GroupTracker
  devid
  groupid
  latitude
  longitude
  timestamp
```

There is only one groupid='1' with groupname="FBorges"
Table GroupLocator has 2 records where devid points to grouid='1' on GroupMembership
GroupTracker has two records where groupid='1'

When I run the following SELECT:

```
SELECT GroupLocator.name, GroupLocator.color, GroupLocator.sampling,
       GroupLocator.forget, GroupLocator.connected, GroupLocator.trace,  
       Groups.groupname, GroupTracker.latitude, GroupTracker.longitude, 
       GroupTracker.timestamp  
FROM GroupMembership 
JOIN GroupLocator    ON GroupLocator.devid=GroupMembership.devid
JOIN Groups          ON Groups.groupid=GroupMembership.groupid 
JOIN GroupTracker    ON GroupTracker.groupid=GroupMembership.groupid 
WHERE GroupMembership.groupid=1;
```

I get the result:

```
name     color sampling forget connected trace groupname  latitude  longitude  timestamp  
PCBorges 2     1        45     0         1     FBorges  -22.883639 -42.822542  2020-01-08 20:29:24
Test     3     2        45     1         0     FBorges  -22.883639 -42.822542  2020-01-08 20:29:24
PCBorges 2     1        45     0         1     FBorges  -22.873639 -42.322542  2020-01-11 16:56:30
Test     3     2        45     1         0     FBorges  -22.873639 -42.322542  2020-01-11 16:56:30
```

What I hope to get is:

```
name     color sampling forget connected trace groupname  latitude  longitude  timestamp 
PCBorges 2     1        45     0         1     FBorges  -22.883639 -42.822542  2020-01-08 20:29:24
Test     3     2        45     1         0     FBorges  -22.883639 -42.822542  2020-01-08 20:29:24
```

Comment: Is your expected result correct? Do you want the same timestamp on both records? Now that I can see your structure and data, I find this expected result strange.

Comment: Pan, timestamp should be as is, no grouping or order necessary. As I said I got it working with your suggestion but I am still interested in finding out why the design is less then optimal, I am just learning SQL and using exemples form the net. Thanks

Comment: My answer will give you the timestamp of `2020-01-11 16:56:30` on the `Test` row. Looking at your structure, I strongly believe that this is what you want. However, your expected result indicates that you want the timestamp `2020-01-08 20:29:24` on both rows. If so, my answer is incorrect in its current form, and @forpas answer is closer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Removed my previous speculation after structure and data was provided and wrote a new answer**:

I believe that you want to JOIN GroupTracker on devid instead of on groupid. Groupid 1 matches both rows in the GroupTracker table, so it will provide two results for each 1 row in GroupMemebership. Devid only matches one row. A correct JOIN is more efficient than your current GROUP BY solution (in comments) and may also produce more consistent results as your database grows.

```
SELECT gl.name, gl.color, gl.sampling,
   gl.forget, gl.connected, gl.trace,  
   g.groupname, gt.latitude, gt.longitude, 
   gt.timestamp  
FROM GroupMembership AS gm
JOIN GroupLocator AS gl    ON gm.devid = gl.devid
JOIN Groups AS g           ON gm.groupid = g.groupid 
JOIN GroupTracker AS gt    ON gm.devid = gt.devid 
WHERE gm.groupid=1
;
```

I aliased all your tables so the query is much shorter and hence faster to write. I also swapped positions of all your JOIN clauses. I prefer to have the left table on the left side and the right table on the right side. Makes it easier to read. These two changes are not important. It's only style. The query will work perfectly without them.

Comment: It is way more advanced than what I can understand.

Comment: @paulo-borges Provide sample data from all your tables as well as your expected result. Then we can provide you with the correct SQL query to get that result set.

Comment: Hi, I tried to format it properly but seems it did not go well.

Comment: Hi Peter, hope you can use the tables provided above. What I am getting and what I would like to get is at the main question above. What I want is to list all records on the GroupLocator table, Groups.groupname and respective GroupTracker records that are on the same GroupMembership.groupid. The SELECT statement will get groupid from the app. Thanks

Comment: Without data, your question is too vague. You are clearly making mistakes in your JOIN statements, but I cannot pinpoint where without some data.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Groups` (
  `groupid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `admin` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastUse` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)    INSERT INTO `Groups` (`groupid`, `groupname`, `admin`, `lastUse`) VALUES
(1, 'FBorges', '90d1b3df5b7b10f3', '2020-01-08 09:45:41');

Comment: CREATE TABLE `GroupMembership` (
  `groupid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `devid` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `GroupMembership` (`groupid`, `devid`) VALUES
(1, '90d1b3df5b7b10f3'),
(1, '90d1b3df5b7b10f4');
COMMIT;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `GroupTracker` (
  `devid` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `groupid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)    
INSERT INTO `GroupTracker` (`devid`, `groupid`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `timestamp`) VALUES
('90d1b3df5b7b10f3', 1, '-22.883639', '-42.822542', '2020-01-08 20:29:24'),
('90d1b3df5b7b10f4', 1, '-22.873639', '-42.322542', '2020-01-11 16:56:30');
COMMIT;

Comment: NN=NOT NULL 
CREATE TABLE `GroupLocator` (
  `devid` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NN,
  `name` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NN,
  `pass` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NN,
  `color` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NN,
  `sampling` int(12) NN,
  `forget` int(12) NN,
  `connected` tinyint(1) NN DEFAULT '0',
  `trace` tinyint(1) NN DEFAULT '0'
)
INSERT INTO `GroupLocator` (`devid`, `name`, `pass`, `color`, `sampling`, `forget`, `connected`, `trace`) VALUES
('90d1b3df5b7b10f3', 'PCBorges', 'gen99ius', 2, 1, 45, 0, 1),
('90d1b3df5b7b10f4', 'Test', 'test', 3, 2, 45, 1, 0);

Comment: Dear Pan, above are the tables structures and current data. I solved the problem by following your suggestion and adding "WHERE GroupMembership.groupid='1' group by GroupLocator.devid" but you mention it is a bad design and I do not understand why.  A user logs in, I find his group checking GroupMembership and from there the purpose of this SELECT would be to get all records from GroupLocator that are from the same group according to the table GroupMembership, then get their current GPS(lat/long) that are on the table GroupTracker, the Groups table only provide the group's name and admin.

Comment: Using GROUP BY on its own does not indicate bad design. I use it often to get aggregate results like COUNT(), SUM() etc. However, if you want to SELECT a value that is different in all the joined rows and you only want one result, you don't necessarily know which row the single value will be taken from and this may indicate bad design (unless you want the MIN(), MAX() etc.). In order to do this, you will need to use the ANY_VALUE() function or ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY must be turned OFF on your server (default on in newer versions). In your case, I believe that you simply joined on the wrong column.

Comment: Just tested your last suggestion, works perfectly, I am dropping my previous select (with the group by) and adopting this optimized one. Thanks a lot for your time, effort and patience. Regards.